# How to incorporate a chorus sheet?

Tags: theory, sheet-music, history

I'm in the process of re-producing some sheet music from the Civil War. My question involves the 'chorus sheet' found at the end of nearly every piece. For example, in this song: *Save Our Flag*, the song seems to end without a clear indication of when the chorus (last page) should be played/sung. Should it be sung after every verse? Only at the end? Anyone have experience with this formatting? I've attached the PDF Score Sheet below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4dc26r34pic0h34/Save%20Our%20Flag%20.pdf?dl=0

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chorus is the same as the refrain. Like phoog says it is sung between the verse and at the end it can be repeated.

In this example it is really a *chorus* while the verse seems to be performed by a soloist.

If we didn’t know that it is sung after each verse we could derive it from the first word of the chorus: “THEN ...” ( this implies that that the chorus refers to each verse.)

Comment: Thanks so much! This was really helpful. If you have a minute, could you take a look at this piece? I'm specifically struggling with the _repeat chorus_ text on the final page. Would the chorus be considered all three lines on the chorus sheet, and all would be repeated? https://www.dropbox.com/s/yccfetn2926sl5y/What%20Will%20They%20Say%20in%20Michigan%20.pdf?dl=0

Comment: The chorus is meant to be repeated all 3 verses (pp).

Answer (score 2):

The chorus is generally sung after every verse.  That is certainly the case here.